# Failed to issue an identity to a participant instance with composer in CLI

Tags: identity, hyperledger-composer

I have followed the instruction in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/participant-add.html to add a participant instance successfully. But when issuing an identity to that participant instance by instruction in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/identity-issue.html, I got error message as follows:

***Error: error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Object with ID 'Participant:resource:net.biz.PropertyNetwork.Person' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist)***

Would you please give me any hints that I can move forwards to address this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is (eg.)

```
 composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n 'digitalproperty-network' -i admin -s adminpw -u maeid1 -a "net.biz.digitalPropertyNetwork.Person#mae@biznet.org"
```

Will get the doc updated. Should remove the 'resource:' in the -a parameter.

Comment: ps. can I ask what composer version you were using (please post?  `composer -v`  - reason I ask, is because later editions of composer should use the URI standard definition, ie with leading 'resource:' (eg. participant -> identity relationship)

Comment: i have upgraded to the composer version v0.11.3 right now. The last version  i used is v0.9.2 in which I suffered from the problem above.

Comment: In the later version of v0.11.3, whether using the leading 'resource' or not after option -a in issuing identity command, it works anyway.

Comment: correct - we're just following the correct URI notation to use, but we now 'catch' it if resource: is omitted. Thanks for trying it :-)